# Returning value from a function in webpack ES6 - scope

Tags: javascript

I am returning a value in a webpack module, however I am unable to use it outside of the function. Unless I am making a silly tired mistake, I think perhaps I am missing something fundamental about the way modules work. Could someone enlighten me please?

```
function getProjectID() {
  const project_id = document.getElementById('project-title')
                              .getAttribute('data-project-id');
  console.log("Project id inside is" + project_id); //Logs out the correct value
  return project_id;
}

getProjectID();

console.log("Project id outside is" + project_id); //Uncaught ReferenceError: project_id is not defined
```

Comment: Where is module.exports being set? That's not in the example code you posted.

Comment: But further... it looks like there's a fundamental misunderstanding of scope here. When you call `console.log('...' + project_id)` the `project_id` variable is undefined. You'll need to invoke `getProjectID` in the `console.log` call.

Comment: `return` does not mean that the *variable* is suddenly going to appear in the caller's scope. Only the *value* is being `return`ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has function scope, so the `project_id` is not going to be accessible outside the function since that's where it's declared.

Assign the return value to access it:

```
const project_id = getProjectID();
```

Comment: if he's writing es5 `const` is not a defined keyword. An exception would be thrown.

Comment: He's using `const` in his original question, though.  So I'm assuming he's using ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code and question it's hard to tell what you actually want to return but I'm guessing you want a module that would return the value of `data-project-id` attribute from `#project-title`.

If my assumption is correct then you need to actually set the `module.exports` to be the `getProjectID` function.

getProjectId.js

```
module.exports = function getProjectID() {
    return document.getElementById('project-title').getAttribute('data-project-id');
}
```

*Note: whether you define the module.exports function as anonymous or not does not matter, but for clarity I maintained the name.*

someOtherFile.js

```
var getProjectId = require('getProjectId');
console.log('Project id is... %s', getProjectID());
```